# Looking for patterns in date time data

Tags: data-mining, anomaly-detection

I am collecting a large amount of date/time statistics in a mysql database about random people connecting to my computer.  Time is represented as oob_time_sec and is converted from_unix(oob_time_sec) to a string containing an actual date and time.  I am collecting a variety of data including time,source port,destination port.

I am looking for a way to analyze the data to see if there are any patterns.
For example:

Every tuesday at 8am someone tries to connect.
  Monthly this pattern happens

```
SELECT *, BIN_TO_IPV6(`ip_saddr_bin`) AS `ip_saddr_bin2`, from_unixtime(oob_time_sec) as oob_time_sec
FROM `ulog`
WHERE `ip_saddr_bin` in (select `ip_saddr_bin` from `ulog` GROUP BY `ip_saddr_bin`
HAVING count(`ip_saddr_bin`)>1)
ORDER BY `ip_saddr_bin`
LIMIT 1000;
```

Will display a given source IP history.  However, I would like to get automated analysis and report.

> Question
>
> 1. Does free/open source software exist to analyze the data?
> 2. Reasonable priced software, say
> 3. If I have to write it, what formulas and equations do I need.

Pre-coded mysql procedures would be ideal.  However, if there is PHP code or a program I can connect to my mysql database that would also work.  I could try and convert actual mathematical equations into a program my self, but that would be my least favorite option.

Eventually, if possible I would like to group them into possible group individual botnets.

Regarding patterns:

Here are some examples of what I am looking for, any other events that repeat on any time scale(second,minute,hour,day,week,month,year,etc).

1. What times are the scanners most/least active? example 8:09-9:41
2. Referring to 1 does that change at all? (daily,hourly,weekly,etc)
3. What are the neighbors doing. start of neighborhood =(((conv(hex(ip_saddr_bin),16,10))>>8)<<8) from to that plus 255.
4. How often do they try neighbors.

Comment: Are you looking for a particular predefined pattern (like the one you mentioned in the original post) or for whatever pattern may be mined from the data? In other words, is your question about pattern matching or actual data mining?

Comment: I am not looking for a predefined pattern, I am looking for "Whatever patterns maybe mined from the data". @DYZ

Comment: Then you should define what a "pattern" is. Otherwise your question is too broad.